# Is neo4j-jdbc driver 3.x thread safe

Tags: jdbc, neo4j, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm running a setup where I use a jdbc API installing neo4j-jdbc driver to connect to the neo4j database in VM, and I ran into a deadlock issue when doing some multi-thread works. I wonder if anyone knows if the neo4j-jdbc driver 3.x is thread safe or not?

Error Log

```
Exception: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.TransientException: LockClient[4211] can't wait on resource RWLock[NODE(2410), hash=1674994875] since => LockClient[4211] <-[:HELD_BY]- RWLock[NODE(2403), hash=1544505462] <-[:WAITING_FOR]- LockClient[4205] <-[:HELD_BY]- RWLock[NODE(2410), hash=1674994875]
org.neo4j.jdbc.bolt.BoltPreparedStatement.executeBatch(BoltPreparedStatement.java:178)
org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:345)
org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:345)
org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$Write$WriteFn.finishBundle(JdbcIO.java:480)
Caused By: org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.TransientException: LockClient[4211] can't wait on resource RWLock[NODE(2410), hash=1674994875] since => LockClient[4211] <-[:HELD_BY]- RWLock[NODE(2403), hash=1544505462] <-[:WAITING_FOR]- LockClient[4205] <-[:HELD_BY]- RWLock[NODE(2410), hash=1674994875]
org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.SocketResponseHandler.handleFailureMessage(SocketResponseHandler.java:71)
org.neo4j.driver.internal.messaging.PackStreamMessageFormatV1$Reader.unpackFailureMessage(PackStreamMessageFormatV1.java:464)
org.neo4j.driver.internal.messaging.PackStreamMessageFormatV1$Reader.read(PackStreamMessageFormatV1.java:425)
org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.SocketClient.receiveOne(SocketClient.java:130)
org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.SocketConnection.receiveOne(SocketConnection.java:143)
Stack trace truncated. Please see Cloud Logging for the entire trace.
```

Comment: What kind of deadlock issue? Please show the error logs.

Comment: updated the description with error log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deadlock is a result of "normal" neo4j behavior in the presence of concurrent requests. You should be aware of neo4j's [default locking behavior](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#transactions-locking), and the [documentation on deadlocks](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#transactions-deadlocks).

This may be the most helpful paragraph:

> Experiencing frequent deadlocks is an indication of concurrent write
>   requests happening in such a way that it is not possible to execute
>   them while at the same time live up to the intended isolation and
>   consistency. The solution is to make sure concurrent updates happen in
>   a reasonable way. For example given two specific nodes (A and B),
>   adding or deleting relationships to both these nodes in random order
>   for each transaction will result in deadlocks when there are two or
>   more transactions doing that concurrently. One solution is to make
>   sure that updates always happens in the same order (first A then B).
>   Another solution is to make sure that each thread/transaction does not
>   have any conflicting writes to a node or relationship as some other
>   concurrent transaction. This can for example be achieved by letting a
>   single thread do all updates of a specific type.

Comment: Thank you the answer. The setup I have does not allow the threads to follow certain order, and neither can I put a `try` and `catch` clause to do a retry. However I was able to work around that issue by using a `neo4j-java-driver` and creating a new driver for each thread, since a java-driver is **thread safe**. That's why I'm wondering if the `neo4j-jdbc-driver` is also **thread safe** or not.

Comment: A thread safe driver will not prevent deadlocks. The only way to avoid neo4j deadlocks is by understanding how neo4j automatic locking works and how you can work around that when necessary.

Comment: by the way neo4j-jdbc 3.X is using neo4j-java-driver under the hood and the transaction is demanded to it. I can assume that if neo4j-java-driver is ok for you, the same will be for the neo4j-jdbc driver (if you are using of course the BOLT protocol)